# Can I perform a distribution upgrade without rebooting?

Tags: upgrade

I would, ideally, like to run a distribution upgrade that doesn't end in a complete reboot of the machine (owing to an irritation in my hardware that requires a period of disconnection from the power supply before my SSD can be detected).

What would be the procedure for doing this from a desktop environment?

I would image:

1. dist-upgrade
2. shutdown all graphical services
3. restart X

I'd appreciate any advice (particularly on the exact procedure for step 2, if this correct). NB. I'm using KSplice for in-memory kernel patching, so the kernel is already dealt with.

Many thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to restart dbus.  I thought I remember reading somewhere that restarting dbus (for when dbus is upgraded) would restart x too, so they opted for a reboot.

But since you want all that: sudo service dbus restart

Comment: Many thanks! If someone could confirm this, I'll mark as accepted as I have no way of testing myself until a dist upgrade is available.

Comment: Just a suggestion to test: install an older version of Ubuntu on an unused PC/laptop or even on a VM created *ex profeso*  and upgrade it to the latest version, trying what user1974 suggests.

Comment: Just attempted to test this under VirtualBox. Sadly, during the distribution upgrade process the guest OS froze and, on hard reset, the root FS was corrupted.

Comment: Hi, just tried this: sudo service dbus restart, which shutdown X, but then did not bring it back up... any idea?

Comment: hey Martin, there were some other questions just like this one a few days ago.  The answers were very good.  What I remember is that linux, dbus, and libc are the packages that need a restart.  
In regards to X not starting again, I dunno.  Works-for-me.  Maybe try `startx` or `sudo service gdm restart`

Comment: I may well be wrong, but I think that if your upgrade includes changes to the kernel, or any modules, you need to restart your machine.

Comment: @thomas, Ksplice is supposed to allow you to upgrade your kernel without upgrades.